# Printf arguments order is being ignored

Tags: c++, c, printf

Am I using this function correctly? I have never seen this happen before:

```
printf("Pulled value %d from index %d\n", prev[block_size-k+i], block_size-k+i);
printf("Pulled value %d from index %d\n", block_size-k+i, prev[block_size-k+i]);
```

output

```
Pulled value 7 from index 0
Pulled value 7 from index 0
```

You can see that the order of the arguments isn't mattering right now. I'm completely lost

I will also split them up for clarity

```
printf("Pulled value %d\n", prev[block_size-k+i]);
printf("from index %d\n", block_size-k+i);
```

output

```
Pulled value 0
from index 7
```

Comment: Please paste the entire code you're running.

Comment: Which function? `printf`? And whats your problem?

Comment: In addition to Barry's comment, make it an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No, it's not expected behavior, it's impossible.

Comment: Are the 2 printf statements together or do you have code between the statements?

Comment: These prints are sequential and are only run one time. Although the contents of the prev array are doubles, not ints

Comment: @user1364759 you used `%d`. use `%f` for `double`.

Comment: switching the %d to %f to accurately print out a float fixed the prints. I will post back if that does not solve my issue. Thanks guys

Comment: Will you fix your question to contain that critical information you finally gave 6 minutes before? That is btw. the reason you should have posted an MCVE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Although the contents of the prev array are doubles, not ints

This is your problem. The type of the argument must match the type expected by printf, and there is no automatic checking for this on most compilers. `%d` is for int type, use `%f` for float or insert a cast to int.

A float has a different format of the bytes it is made from, and on many systems is eight bytes (technically, float is automatically converted to double when passed to printf) whereas int is four, so it's just a coincidence that your two print statements looked the same.

Comment: Yeah just running `printf("Got %d and %d.\n", 1.0, 7)` with gcc prints "Got 0 and 1072693248" so... yeah, let's just stick with correct formatting!

Comment: This is an interesting issue. The ignored ordering is what threw me off. I will remember not to be lazy with the data type representations in the future

Comment: @user1364759 It's undefined behavior, so maybe the result of some optimization that wouldn't matter if you did it correctly. Maybe it passes float arguments in a register in some situations... did you include stdio.h/cstdio?

Answer (score 0):

If `prev` is a double use `%f` as placeholder:

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    double a = 0;
    int b = 7;


    printf("Pulled value %.0f from index %d\n", a, b);
    printf("Pulled value %d from index %.0f\n", b, a);



    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
Pulled value 0 from index 7
Pulled value 7 from index 0
```